# Выдает ora - 904

Tags: sql, oracle

Доброго всем времени суток. Существует такая проблема
В запросе

```
select fio, column_name, cast(n as number(15,4)) as a
from table1 p join table2 d on p.fio = d.fio
unpivot (n for column_name in
( column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, wtf))
```

Ругается на ошибку ora 00904 - инвалидный идентификатор fio

column1~3 лежат в table1, column4~5 и wtf лежат в table2

Запрос

```
select fio, column_name, cast(n as number(15,4)) as a
from cc_emp_kpi_perf unpivot (n for column_name in
(column1, column2, column3))
union all
select fio, column_name, cast(n as number(15,4)) as a
from cc_emp_kpi_disc unpivot (n for column_value in
(column4, column5, wtf ))
```

Возвращает данные только из первой таблицы.
Поля fio в обеих таблицах идентичны.

Не могу понять, как связать эти две таблицы и получить одну в виде

fio   -   column_name   -  a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено запросом

```
select fio, column_name, cast(n as number(15,4)) as a
from 
(select p.fio,column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, wtf 
from table1 p join table2 d on p.fio = d.fio)
unpivot (n for column_name in
( column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, wtf))
```